# Can you translate this Chinese chop?

Tags: translation, meaning, seal

I bought this is Taiwan probably 30 years ago, not sure what it means.  Can you help translate?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

麥宏 in bronze/seal script inspired font.

As for meaning, it is almost undoubtably a name and in that sense has no meaning to define or translate.  However here is a link to wikipedia for each individual character below if you would like to know more, and you could transcribe the name as Mai Hong in pinyin.  Also it is fairly gender nuetral. (◐‿◑)﻿

[https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/麥](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%BA%A5)

[https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/宏](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%AE%8F)